Confusing with estimating the voltage at an IC terminals
I cannot find the input impedance of A and B pins for this IC. Cannot be sure is that 20kOhm?
And the reason I'm looking for it I'm wondering the voltage divider effect for the following way of use:

So if I'm not wrong the voltage at A or B is affected by the input resistance correct? How can we estimate the voltage seen at A and B comparing to the wire voltages Va and Vb which represents before connected to the IC.
So lets say "before connected to the IC" Vb is -5V and Va is +5V with respect to Ic ground. What happens to the voltage at A and B when the wires are connected to A and B considering those 4.7k pullup and pulldown resistors?

But Vb is pulled to 0V. It would not have -5V unless some other chip drives the bus. Do you mean 0V, if only the bias resistors shown are considered?

The datasheet linked in the question is from a 3rd party website and is "Version 1.03, 2022/05/18". The datasheet on the CA-IS3082W manufacuter's  Chipanalog site is the later "Version 1.08, 2023/11/13" which has an updated section 7.7.2. Receiver with a different value of the Differential input resistance parameter. Does that help?

@Justme I mean when it acts as a receiver not transmitter. When it acts as a driver it will pull down to gnd. But I was wondering the voltage divider effect of Rin and 4.7k resistors when the chip is receiver mode.

@pnatk - Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF/video name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page etc. TY

@SamGibson Its a general topology using pullup pulldown resistor. So it doesnt matter that particular one. Its just an example. But will update it sure.

@pnatk I understand, but why would there be -5V on Vb if there is nothing setting it to -5V? Do you mean 0V instead of -5V? You can't habe one wire at +5V and other at -5V, that's outside RS-485 specs.

@pnatk - Re: "it doesnt matter that particular one" Yes, it does matter. Including copied / adapted material on Stack Exchange without a correct reference is plagiarism and is a Code of Conduct (inauthentic usage) violation. That is treated seriously by Stack Exchange and, therefore, by mods. Therefore, for your own benefit, please do not think that "it doesn't matter". Re: "will update it sure". Thank you, please do. || I can delete these meta comments when a correct reference for the copied material has been added.

The datasheet for the chip you linked to boasts 20 kohm input impedance.
It's slightly higher than what RS-485 defines as one unit load which is 12 kohms which allows 32 receivers on bus.
You can assume the 20 kohms impedance is between A and B inputs and it allows 50 receivers on bus.
In reality there is no single resistor between pins, but more complex network to supply, ground and in series, with protection networks to limit the voltage within allowed range.
So assuming purely with the impedance assumption, and no leakage currents, there will be 3.4V between pins A and B, with simple voltage divider formula.
The resistors are somewhat useless though, as this chip already has input fail-safe feature, but it may help other chips on the bus that don't have that feature.
Also the voltage won't be 3.4V when connected to a terminated bus. The input impedance of one receiver is practically irrelevant. The bus will be terminated with 120 ohms on both ends, so it will be a 60 ohm DC load. On a terminated bus with only these failsafe bias resistors, there will be only about 30mV between A and B, which by RS-485 is not a very good failsafe bias, as it should be more than 200mV to guarantee all receivers have a defined logic level.
That's why there can be 32 receivers with 12 kohm inputs, or 50 with 20 kohm inputs.
The failsafe bias resistors are extra loads themselves so with them the bus does not allow 32 unit loads but somewhat less.

Yes you are correct  (+5V and -5V), it results in a 10V, which clearly violates the RS-485 differential voltage limit. My example was not good... But the reason I asked this question I was wondering if 4.7k pullup pulldown resistors have any effect in mitigating a possible CM voltage or CM noise ect. Can you also write a few word about it? Thanks

@pnatk It was not in the original question. And the pull-down will pull to 0V, there is no -5V anywhere. The bias resistors, along with proper termination resistors that must be added separately, will actually keep the A and B lines at about 2.5V CM bias compared to GND of this chip, which makes it work without the ground connection that's left off as they let the GND and VCC to track the bus CM because this is an isolated chip. RS-485 receives differentially and allows +/- 7V of CM voltage between chips anyway.
